# Как правильнее инициализировать данные класса для работы с БД SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

У меня есть класс, который предоставляет методы для работы с БД, при чем это единственный класс, который работает с БД в программе:

```
public class ForwardersHelper {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public void addForwarder(Forwarder forwarder) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public void deleteForwarder(int forwarderId) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public void changeForwarder(Forwarder forwarder) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public ArrayList<Forwarder> getForwardersList() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public int getFreeForwarderId() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

---

У меня есть два варианта инициализации подключения к БД: сделать все статическим и обращаться к классу без экземпляров или открывать подключение, через соответствующие методы:

---

Вариант 1:

```
    public class ForwardersHelper {
        private static DBHelper dbHelper;
        private static SQLiteDatabase db;

        public static void init(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        @Override
        //Во время уничтожения объекта уборщиком мусора, закроются все подключения, так
        //как этот метод вызывается автоматически
        public void finalize() {
            db.close();
            dbHelper.close();

            try {
                super.finalize();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ...
        ...
        ...


    }
```

При старте программы в активности или классе `Application` вызвать метод `ForwardersHelper.init(this)`. По скольку статические методы инициализируются один раз и навсегда — при таком вызове откроется подключение к БД и работа с методами будет доступна по всей программе.

---

Вариант 2:

```
public class ForwardersHelper {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public void openDBConnection(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void closeDBConnection(Context context) {
        db.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Затем, после создания каждого экземпляра, вызывать `openDBConnection()`, а после его использования вызывать `closeDBConnection()`.

---

Я склоняюсь к первому варианту, потому что он удобнее в использовании, будет получаться меньше кода в остальных классах и код будет понятнее, но код станет немного сложнее для понимания и у меня сомнения на счет правильности `finalize()`. Второй же вариант понятнее для того, кто его читает, но и станет немного больше и потеряет выразительность. Какой вариант все же будет правильнее и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С моей точки зрения оба ваши варианты не правильны. По хорошему большинство из ваших классов, которые вы создаете, не должен знать о том что существует контекст, активити или фрагмент. Это уменьшит связность кода, а так же в будущем упростит тестирование, рефакторинг и в случае чего код можно будет легко вынести в отдельный модуль. Так же при написании кода лучше лучше использовать принцип внедрения зависимостей(DI). Т.е. класс, в вашем случае `ForwardersHelper`, не сам должен создавать объект `SQLiteDatabase`, а должен получать его через конструктор, специальный метод, или как то еще, но главное что бы он не создавал его сам. Это легко позволит при необходимости подменять реализации зависимостей, что так же облегчит расширение кода, тестирование кода и позволит легко внедрить какую либо библиотеку для DI.

Исходя из перечисленного у меня класс `ForwardersHelper` выглядел бы так.

```
public class ForwardersHelper {
    private final DBHelper dbHelper;
    private final SQLiteDatabase db;

    public ForwardersHelper(DBHelper dbHelper, SQLiteDatabase db){
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
        this.db = db;
    }

    // Остальной код
}
```

Если хочется Singleton, то можно сделать так:

```
public class ForwardersHelper {

    private static final ForwardersHelper INSTANCE = new ForwardersHelper();

    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static ForwardersHelper getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private ForwardersHelper(){
    }

    public void init(DBHelper dbHelper, SQLiteDatabase db){
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
        this.db = db;
    }

    // Остальной код
}
```

Инициализируем один раз в `Application.onCreate()` и дальше используем как хотим.

В случае чего такой код можно быстро переписать с использованием `Dagger2`.

Закрывать БД вручную нет необходимости. Соединение закроется когда система убьет приложение. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739454/3918680).

Comment: А какой смысл исключать из класса создание конкретной БД, если его реализация "заточена" на взаимодействие конкретно с этой БД?

Comment: @bukashka101 смысл в том, чтобы класс не знал откуда взять базу. Ваш класс для работы с бд должен знать только как работать с ней, а не как создавать ее или откуда взять. Так же это облегчит тестирование выборки из бд, т.к. легко можно будет подсунуть тестовую готовую, про которую вы будите знать сколько и каких объектов там лежит.

Comment: Немного не понимаю, чем это легче. Класс же не создает базу, а читает ее! Да и какая разница между подставкой базы в классе и извне, код же будет аналогичным?

Comment: @bukashka101 в вашем случае класс сам принимает решение откуда взять базу, хотя он должен всего лишь читать ее. Плюс ко всему вы привязываете его к контексту что так же не очень хорошо. Чем меньше класс знает об окружающей среде, тем проще его впоследствии будет расширять, изменять, тестировать.

Comment: То есть смысл в том, чтобы я ему не отдавал контекст, а только базу для того, чтобы потом изменять поведение класса с этой БД?

Comment: @bukashka101 смысл в отвязки от контекста и снятия с класса обязанности создавать объект бд

Comment: Читал сегодня книгу и понял о чем Вы говорите! Вы говорите о слабом связывании! Один класс должен знать минимум о другом (в моем случае - контексте). Но, в данной ситуации, я не понимаю, зачем это нужно. В любом случае класс `ForwardersHelper` заточен именно под `SQLite`, именно с этой таблицей, а таблица именно под это приложение. Класс попросту нигде не будет применяться ни в каких других программах, а суть слабого связывания (на сколько я понял) - улучшить транспортируемость и упростить класс. Со сложностью у него, вроде бы, проблем нет, а транспортируемость не нужна.

Comment: Выгоду в тестировании я не вижу, потому что еще не тестирую приложения своими тестами, а просто проверяю работоспособность методом "потыкать во все". :)

Answer (score 1):

используйте **[Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))**
для инициализации объекта подключения к базе.

Внутри каждого метода вызывайте

```
db.getInstance() // а дальше работаете
```

Синглтон позволяет получить объект такой, что если он не инициализирован, то сначала инициазилирует и вернет

```
SQLiteDatabase getInstance()
    {
      if(db == null){
      db = new ....
      db.connect();
    }else{
      if(!db.isConnected())
        {db.connect()}

    retetn db;
}
```

Это упрощает жизнь и читабельность кода

Comment: Тогда есть одно "но" — мне нужно передать контекст, то есть или инициализировать, или создать хотя бы один объект, который инициализирует статическую переменную базы данных.

Comment: так это и упрощает синглтон. ты один раз инициализируешь и забываешь о нем

Comment: Хм... Действительно, неплохой выход из ситуации. Но все же этот класс нужно получать каждый раз, тогда как к статическому варианту можно обращаться сразу и напрямую и, аналогично статическому варианту, ему придется закрывать подключение, через `finalizе()`, а меня волнует вопрос: стоит ли использовать вариант с `finaliza()` или без него, и почему, а так же стоит держать открытой БД или лучше после одноразового использования закрывать подключение.

Comment: коннект закроется автоматически после завершения программы.
лучше оставляй открыто, так как подключения займет секунды 3. если ты много раз обращаешься к базе, то оставляй открыто. в моем проекте по 6ч коннект открыт и все работает штатно.

Comment: 3 секунды? :о Чего так много? У меня и секунды не проходит!

Comment: может в отличии базы и драйвера

Comment: А они чем-то отличаются? И какой драйвер?О.о

Comment: jDBC mySQL
A Hibernate вообще 10 сек подключается

Comment: А... Я до такого не дошел. Из нестандартных библиотек я только `EventBus` брал. И то для поддержки костылей :). Сейчас пытаюсь встать на "путь истинный" и писать нормально. "Совершенный код" прочитал, "Head First: Android", сейчас "Философия Java" читаю.